# Azure WVD Hostpool - Virtual Network displaying "None available"

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azureportal, vnet, wvd

I keep encountering an irritating blocker when attempting to create a Host Pool for my project's Windows Virtual Desktop (WVD) in Azure and I'm at my wits end figuring out what could be causing this issue.

My existing resource group contains the following resources (all fully setup and configured):

1. A VNet
2. Security Group
3. Key Vault

All of the above resources can be confirmed via the Portal, Azure Powershell and Az CLI.

However, when attempting to create the Host Pool for the WVD which is the next resource we're seeking to provision manually through the Portal, I get prompted to **Add virtual machines** and upon selecting the option to add a virtual machine, I'm prompted to complete the Network and security configuration. However, the Virtual network dropdown isn't populated with any list, rather showing as "None available".

The Virtual Network definitely exists and I can't understand why the dropdown list continues to be empty. I've deleted and recreated the entire resource group on a number of occasions but all to no avail. Any advice or suggestions on how to get past this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for updating your solution. I face exact same problem and follow your guidance and find that my VNET is in a different region v.s. the host pool.

Originally I can not find the drop down item in the virtual network either, my workaround is to create a VNET in the same region on host pool and now I can select it.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to establish what the issue was. It was the selected "Virtual machine location" value that was not allowing me to see the target VNet in the "Virtual network" dropdown list.

By default, Azure was populating the Virtual machine location field with the name of a region where my VNets didn't exist. Once I'd spotted this and switched it to the correct Region, the Virtual network dropdown list further below was populated as expected.